# How to write a universal function to join two PySpark dataframes?

Tags: python, function, join, pyspark, inner-join

How to write a universal function to join two PySpark dataframes?

I want to write a function that performs inner join on two dataframes and also eliminates the repeated common column after joining. As far as I'm aware there is no way to do that, as we always need to define common columns manually while joining. Or is there a way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to include all the common columns in the join condition then you can extract them into a list and pass to `join()`. After the join, just call `drop` on these same columns to eliminate them from the result.

```py
common_cols = list(set(df.columns).intersection(set(df2.columns)))

df3 = df.join(df2, common_cols, how='inner').drop(*common_cols)
```

Comment: This seems useful, but it's dropping the common column entirely. I just want to eliminate the common column repeated twice.

Comment: @AishaniSingh, with inner join it will not repeat twice anyway, so you can ignore the `.drop()`.

Comment: Great this worked! But the common column is becoming the left most (first) column, I want it as second column. How can I do that?

Comment: You can "reorder" columns with a select statement in which you name the columns in the order you want to have. There is no efficiency-related reason to re-order columns in pyspark however. Just eye-candy.